# Convert null terminated string to non-null terminated string in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a code for my project in C. I need to add a loop so that the ip_address can be passed to inet_addr() from the array and I can print the send & receive the data. But my code is only executing till printf("Send \n") and I'm not receiving anything after that. The program seems to just hang up & I'm not getting any errors too. Also, the code is running fine when I'm hardcoding the address(eg."100.12.1.10") directly. I tried various methods but nothing seems to be working. I can't figure it out.
It would be great if you guys have any suggestions.
PS: This is only a part of the whole code and other parts are working fine.

```
unsigned char *ip_address[25] = { "879.120.8.249", 
                                  "232.106.122.6", 
                                  "17.105.176.86", 
                                  "85.195.823.169", ......}         

 for(int k = 0; k < 25; k++) {

        size_t l = strlen(ip_address[k]);
        char address[l];
        //address = (char*)malloc(l);
        memcpy(address, ip_address[k], l+1);
    
        memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
        // Filling server information
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);
        //printf("Ip_address = %s\n", ip_address[k]);
        //printf("address = %s\n", address);

        int n, len=0;
        for(i=0;i<MAXLINE;i++){
        len++;
        if(buffer[i]==62 && buffer[i-1]==62)
            break;  
        }
        printf("Len = %d\n", len);  
        printf("Send \n");
        sendto(sockfd, (const char *)buffer, len,
            MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, 
                sizeof(servaddr));
        printf("before Receive");
        n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)recv_buffer, MAXLINE, 
                    MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,
                    &len);
        printf("after receive");
    
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){   
            printf("%d,", recv_buffer[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        close(sockfd);
    }
```

Comment: If you have the 6-byte string `"Hello"` but send 5 bytes, the `'\0'` will not be sent/received.

Comment: "to non-null terminated _string_ in C" contradicts the C library's definition of _string_.  All C _strings_ have a terminating _null character_.

Comment: Once you know the length of the terminated string, you treat it as a non-terminated array of that length, i.e., simply ignore the terminator.

Comment: Either `char address[l];` needs to be `char address[l+1];` or `memcpy(address, ip_address[k], l+1);` needs to be `memcpy(address, ip_address[k], l);`, otherwise it is a buffer overflow. But the parameter of `inet_addr` needs to be a null-terminated string, so `inet_addr(address);` needs `char address[l+1];`. (It could be replaced with `inet_addr(ip_address[k]);` though, since `ip_address[k]` is null-terminated.)

Comment: You have UB. With your `memcpy`, you are copying the string + the EOS char but you only do: `char address[l];`. You need `char address[l + 1];` to provide space for the EOS

Comment: Actually, just forget about `address` and `memcpy`. What about: `servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address[k]);` directly?

Answer (score 0):

At least these problems:

**Insufficient space**

```
// char address[l];  // too small
char address[l+1];
memcpy(address, ip_address[k], l+1);
```

**Index of -1?**

`buffer[]` not defined, yet `buffer[0-1]` looks strange

```
for(i=0;i<MAXLINE;i++){
  len++;
  if(buffer[i]==62 && buffer[i-1]==62)
    break;  
}
```

Perhaps

```
  //if(buffer[i]==62 && buffer[i-1]==62)
  if(i > 0 && buffer[i]==62 && buffer[i-1]==62)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working today somehow.

```
unsigned char *ip_address[25] = { "879.120.8.249", 
                                  "232.106.122.6", 
                                  "17.105.176.86", 
                                  "85.195.823.169", ......};
```

Here, I changed the *unsigned char* to *const char*, then used the variable directly, and it worked somehow.

```
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address[k]);
```